# Binding Individual row to individual labels

Tags: asp.net

// design

// in design view there are 10 labels (lblq1,lblq2....lblq10)

// Code

public void bindquestions()
    {
        try
        {

```
        strqry = "select DISTINCT feedbackformusers.questionid as questionid,questions.question as question from feedbackformusers inner join questions on feedbackformusers.questionid=questions.questionid where feedbackformusers.empid=@empid and feedbackformusers.feedbackformid=@feedbackformid and feedbackformusers.isactive='yes'";
```

//output of query

//questionid    question

// 1    Teacher covers the whole syllabus prescribed by the University ?

// 2    Make the concept clear, simple and interesting ?

// 3    Simplifies difficult topics by giving examples and makes the lecture interesting.

// 4    Uses logical, purposeful and thought-provoking questions for student participation.

// 5    Availability beyond normal classes and cooperation to solve individual problems.

// 6    Speaks clearly and confidently with adequate loudness.

// 7    Maintains proper discipline in the classroom.

// 8    Motivates the students to grow higher in life and to improve their shortcomings.

// 9    Regularity and punctuality.

// 10   Motivates the students to ask questions and to give answers in the classroom.

```
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strqry, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", ddlemployee.SelectedValue);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feedbackformid",Session["feedbackformid"].ToString());
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        { con.Open(); }

         drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

//i knw the code will written here

// and i want to bind the output questions with 10 labels of the designview.

// I'm confused what to do here, to bind with every individual labels,

// i hope now everyone can understand

```
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('" + a.ToString() + "')", true);
    }
    finally
    {
        drd.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please make the question more readable.

Comment: yes sir ,
i want to bind each of the question i get from query to each label.,
coz i m getting question collectively i.e. 10 and 10 labels are there
how i assign values to every label ?

Answer (score 0):

Am not into asp.net much..
but using an adodb recordset u can access the database with an sql nd get each row from the recordset using its item property and assign it to label.text

in vb.net the label itself has a databinding property.. 
so its simple there.

in asp.net an adodb recordset or oledb table adapter should do fine i suppose

Comment: exactly i want to access via the row index
but nt possible 
or may be i dnt knw how